# @user not showing up in postings

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment Link to OP not Possible](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/comment-link-to-op-not-possible)

I am using a Chrome browser.

Sometimes, when I use "@**user**: {my comment}", the **@user** user name does not show up in the comment posting, but the comment does.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround? It is bothersome as the comment is actually being directed at the specific user.

Regards

Comment: I have promoted the use of !user instead of @user in these cases. The software will not remove the former. It removes the latter under the theory that it already knows who to notify, but the software cannot tell whether you want to include the name for other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are commenting to the author of the question or answer and there are no others commenting on the question or answer to be confused with, the `@user` will be removed.